# Is there any difference between "json" and "tojson" filters in jinja for saltstack?

Tags: json, jinja2, salt-stack

According to saltstack documentation it's "json": 
https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/renderers/all/salt.renderers.jinja.html

But in jinja doc
http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#builtin-filters - there is not "json", but "tojson".

Does anybody know why?

Comment: @doz10us thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While I can't say absolutely for sure, I have an impression that Salt Renderers are built-in for Salt only. For example, there are also `yaml` and `python` renderers, but there is no corresponding filter for Jinja.

So, `json` **renderer** and `tojson` **filter** just happened to have similar names because of their purpose. And you won't be able to use `json` renderer outside of Salt.

Comment: To add a little flavor to this answer..Jinja is an unrelated templating language that saltstack chose to use for a part of itself.  Saltstack also has it's own stuff.  I would not be surprised if there were plenty of duplicate-ish things.  They are not the same software project and seek to solve different goals.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure, but I see `tojson` renders `<script>` tag as string if present in json. The `json` does not and executes the js.