# Passing JSON objects from Flask into JavaScript but special characters are not encoding

Tags: javascript, python, json, flask, jinja2

I need to pass a JSON object from the back end of my flask application to be used by the client. Unfortunately, in the browser, it is not being recognised as a JSON object as the quotemarks get encoded differently.

I use `json.dumps()` in python and then pass this into the browser using `render_template()`. However, once this is passed to the browser, the object appears as so:

```
{&#34;0&#34;: {&#34;word_id&#34;: 5, &#34;body&#34;: &#34;man&#34;, &#34;UWL_id&#34;: 5, &#34;sentences&#34;:
```

Comment: Although I'm not into flask, i may have found an answer for you: You should declare it `safe`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/3206446/9898643

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44299336/is-there-any-difference-between-json-and-tojson-filters-in-jinja-for-saltsta).

It seems that jinja is able to format json in the template using the `|tojson` filter